# liquibase changelog file is not updating from default value

Tags: java, spring-boot, liquibase

I am integrating liquibase into my project. I am able to run the cli command successfully and update the schema as expected.

My issue arises when I try to start the application. I am running the app on spring boot and it fails to start on the following erorr;

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find changelog location: class path resource [db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml] (please add changelog or check your Liquibase configuration)`

Looking into this all last night I seen that it was a simple spring liquibase property that was set to a default value `liquibase.change-log=db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml`. So in my application.properties file I put in the following; `liquibase.change-log=liquibase/db-changelog-master.xml`. Still no luck.

I have changed the `liquibase-change-log` value to be the relative path, absolute path and even started with `classpath:`, all of which to no avail.

Each time I try to start this app I keep getting the same error, that it can't find the `db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml` file. I don't understand why this is not being updated as I have correctly included the right config param to change this default value.

Any information would be much appreciated;

**Full Error**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find changelog location: class path resource [db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml] (please add changelog or check your Liquibase configuration)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:138) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:423) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1702) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1250) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1085) ~[spring-context-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:858) ~[spring-context-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:138) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:751) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:387) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1245) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1233) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
at com.recordz.app.Application.main(Application.java:23) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find changelog location: class path resource [db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml] (please add changelog or check your Liquibase configuration)
at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:94) ~[spring-core-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.checkChangelogExists(LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.java:105) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:369) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:135) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
... 29 common frames omitted
```

**application.properties**

```
# DB Connection
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/recordzdb
spring.datasource.username=ddold

# DB Pooling
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

# port 8080 taken in work
server.port=8090

# LIQUIBASE (LiquibaseProperties)
liquibase.change-log=/home/ddold/Documents/Projects/Recordz/src/main/resources/liquibase/db-changelog-master.xml
#liquibase.change-log=classpath:liquibase/db-changelog-master.xml

debug=true
```

**Pom.xml**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.M7</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <hibernate.version>5.0.0.Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>MultiChainJavaAPI</groupId>
        <artifactId>MultiChainJavaAPI</artifactId>
        <version>0.4.8-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.bettercloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>vault-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20160810</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- For connection pooling -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.6</version>
        <!--<scope>runtime</scope>-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <!-- User liquibase plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/liquibase/db-changelog-master.xml</changeLogFile>
            </configuration>
            <!--<executions>-->
              <!--<execution>-->
                <!--<phase>process-resources</phase>-->
                <!--<goals>-->
                  <!--<goal>update</goal>-->
                <!--</goals>-->
              <!--</execution>-->
            <!--</executions>-->
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.recordz.app.Application</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Directory Structure**

```
resources
|
|___liquibase/
|   |
|   |____changelog/
|   |    |
|   |    |_____db-changelog-1.0.xml
|   |
|   |____db-changelog-master.xml
|   |
|   |____liquibase.properties
|
|___application.properties
```

Comment: Try setting `spring.liquibase.change-log` to the liquibase file path in the config or try `spring.liquibase.changeLog`.

Comment: Thanks Ankur, using `sping.liquibase.changeLog` worked perfectly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found my solution;

In the spring applications.properties file, use `spring.liquibase.changeLog` instead of `liquibase.change-log` and for its value I used `classpath:/liquibase/db-changelog-master.xml`